# convert datauri pdf to file for attaching to email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, data-uri

I am using a basic telerik export document to pdf function.  this works great to export the page directly to the user.  I then pass this to a controller as a string via datauri.

how can I convert it back to a file so that I can attach it to an email?

```
imageData: "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJcLB2s/OCgoxIDAg...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this. replace a bit of the header, convert to byes, make a new stream, attach stream to email.

```
 imageData = imageData.Replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

 Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
 email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("SALOR.pdf",stream);
```